# Rectangular shaped Gradient Fill

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, gradient

I'm currently looking to achieve a gradient effect a bit like the rectangle in http://pjnicholson.com/Fireworks/fillgradients.htm

[image: rectangle fill]

If I compromise a little I can get close to this using RadialGradientBrush... but is there any (not too painful) way to achieve the rectangular effect?

Comment: Gradients look bad on WP7 by default (I think there's a fix by overriding 'banding') but if you can, you should probably just use an image

Comment: @willmel - it sounds like you need to enabled 32 bit color in Mango - bitsperpixel=32 - http://j2i.net/blogEngine/post/2011/11/04/Enable-32-bit-Color-if-Your-Application-Supports-It.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `ImageBrush` instead and use this image (or a similar image generated using some image editor) for the background of your rectangle.

Comment: Agreed - it doesn't sound too elegant, but Silverlight does not support this style of gradient.

Answer (score 2):

One solution a colleague and I came with was to derive a new Panel that used a WriteableBitmap as the source for its background.

The panel will give you the dimensions you need to make your WriteableBitmap.  Using whatever algorithm you want you can fill it appropriately.  In our case, we needed a radial or cone gradient, but the same concept applies.

Additionally, you can create several properties on your new control to specify the colors for the gradient.  We adapted a LinearGradientBrush for our needs, but if you're working on just two colors, simple properties may suffice.

I don't have the code handy but will try to find it and post an update later.  But the above should get you going.